# Autossh options not consistent with what is in its man page?

Tags: ubuntu, autossh

I have kind of a naive question, but by reading this thread for example: https://superuser.com/questions/37738/how-to-reliably-keep-an-ssh-tunnel-open

One can see in the accepted answer how to use `autossh`, e.g.:

```
autossh -M 20000 -f -N your_public_server -R 1234:localhost:22 -C
```

But from the man page of `autossh` https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/autossh.1.html I can only see 3 available options: `-M`, `-f` and `-V`.

Same thing on my system:

```
$ autossh --help
/usr/lib/autossh/autossh: invalid option -- '-'
usage: autossh [-V] [-M monitor_port[:echo_port]] [-f] [SSH_OPTIONS]

    -M specifies monitor port. Overrides the environment
       variable AUTOSSH_PORT. 0 turns monitoring loop off.
       Alternatively, a port for an echo service on the remote
       machine may be specified. (Normally port 7.)
    -f run in background (autossh handles this, and does not
       pass it to ssh.)
    -V print autossh version and exit.

Environment variables are:
    AUTOSSH_GATETIME    - how long must an ssh session be established
                          before we decide it really was established
                          (in seconds). Default is 30 seconds; use of -f
                          flag sets this to 0.
    AUTOSSH_LOGFILE     - file to log to (default is to use the syslog
                          facility)
    AUTOSSH_LOGLEVEL    - level of log verbosity
    AUTOSSH_MAXLIFETIME - set the maximum time to live (seconds)
    AUTOSSH_MAXSTART    - max times to restart (default is no limit)
    AUTOSSH_MESSAGE     - message to append to echo string (max 64 bytes)
    AUTOSSH_PATH        - path to ssh if not default
    AUTOSSH_PIDFILE     - write pid to this file
    AUTOSSH_POLL        - how often to check the connection (seconds)
    AUTOSSH_FIRST_POLL  - time before first connection check (seconds)
    AUTOSSH_PORT        - port to use for monitor connection
    AUTOSSH_DEBUG       - turn logging to maximum verbosity and log to
                          stderr
```

Where do the `-N`, `-R` and `-C` options come from? Am I not looking at the right place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> usage: autossh [-V] [-M monitor_port[:echo_port]] [-f] [SSH_OPTIONS]
> ```

Those are the *`[SSH_OPTIONS]`*, options that are passed as-is by `autossh` to `ssh` and handled by `ssh` there.

See [`man ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1) for those.

Comment: Oh gosh, Ok, I totally misunderstood those! I thought they were referencing the environment variables at the bottom of the help. But then... how is handled the case of the `-f` option which is present in both commands?! And is it also possible with `autossh` to make use an SSH service, manually defined in the `~/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: @s.k: from the usage message you posted in your question: `-f run in background (autossh handles this, and does not pass it to ssh.)`. Read the part in parentheses. I have no idea what an 'SSH service ... in .ssh/config' is -- do you mean some option(s), or a host (or pseudo-host) block? If so, yes `autossh` runs `ssh` and `ssh` uses `config` in the same way as any other run of `ssh`.